# Watch directory of LESS files with Grunt

Tags: css, gruntjs, less

My current Grunt code:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        // running `grunt less` will compile once
        less: {
            development: {
                options: {
                    paths: ["custom"],
                    yuicompress: true
                },
            files: {
                "custom/file1.css": "custom/*.less",
                "custom/file2.css": "custom/*.less"

            }
        }
    },
    // running `grunt watch` will watch for changes
    watch: {
        files: "custom/*.less",
        tasks: ["less"]
    }
});
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['less:development']);

};
```

Rather than specifying two individual files "file1" and "file2", i would prefer it to compile and watch all .less files within "custom".

Comment: See http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#compact-format (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18728776/2712740 for the particular example). (Also note that `yuicompress` option was removed from `grunt-contrib-less` about two years ago).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you have to use the rename callback :

```
files: [{
    src: ['custom/*.less'],
    expand: true,
    rename: function(dest, src) { return dest + src.replace('.less', '.css') },
    dest: ''
}]
```

Source: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less/issues/135

Comment: this works great, thanks. You just missed the "]" closing square bracket off the end. But once i added that, it worked a dream.